# apache ignite cross cache join is not working, showing _Key column not found

Tags: ignite

giving excepting like

```
javax.cache.CacheException: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: Failed to parse query: SELECT "
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.IgniteCacheProxy.query(IgniteCacheProxy.java:760)

Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Column "Orders.ORDERITEM._KEY" not found; SQL statement:
SELECT "Orders".OrderItem._KEY, "Orders".OrderItem._VAL from OrderItem as p, "Distributors".Distributor as org where p.distributorID = org.distributorID [42122-191]
```

Comment: Could you please share your caches configuration (including indexing)?